# How to create a cipher in Java

Tags: java, ascii

Im currently creating code to cipher text in Java using predefined characters. The code is working, except I don't know how to deal with spaces in my code. When the program comes to a space it seems to terminate but I want it to be able to read in and cipher full sentences. Apologies for the poor explanation but hopefully the code will show the problem I'm having.

```
public static final int ASCII_SUB = 96;
public static final int ASCII_SUB_FOR_SPACE = 32;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("Enter the text that you would like to cipher:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cipher = input.next();
    input.close();

    int length = cipher.length();

    char encryption[] = createCipher();
    String encrypted = encrypt(encryption, cipher, length);

    System.out.println(encrypted);


}

public static char[] createCipher(){

    char[] encryption = {'p', 'u', 'y', 'k', 'h', 'q', 'g', 'j', 'l',
            'i', 'd', 'v', 'b', ' ', 'o', 'c', 'f', 'r', 'e', 't', 'x',
            'a', 'n', 'z', 'm', 'g', 'w', 's' };

    return encryption;
}

public static String encrypt(char[] encryption, String cipher, int length){

    String lowercaseCipher = cipher.toLowerCase();
    char[] characterArray = lowercaseCipher.toCharArray();

    char[] test = new char[length];
    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        if(characterArray[i] == ' '){
            test[i] = (char) (characterArray[i] - ASCII_SUB_FOR_SPACE);
        }
        else{
            test[i] = (char) (characterArray[i] - ASCII_SUB);
        }

    char test2[] = new char[length];

    for(int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        test2[i] = encryption[test[i]];
    }

    String anotherString = new String( test2 );
    return anotherString;
}
```

When I enter something like "ab aq".

The program prints out "uy"

Thanks in advance

Comment: ASCII space is 32, so subtracting 96 will generate some non-printable character

Comment: I edited the program by adding an if else statement to try and deal with spaces but it still terminates when it reaches the space character

Comment: Your variable names are a little wonky.  Your code would be cleaner (easier to understand) if the array returned by createCipher() was assigned to a variable named "cipher", if the text that you read in from the console was held in variables named "plainTextAsString" and "plainTextAsBytes", if the variable that you call "test2" was named "cipherTextAsBytes", etc.

Comment: Java strings don't use ASCII; They use Unicode. Your algorithm seems to work on a very limited set of characters: space and lowercase [Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) characters. You could restrict acceptable user input like this `if (characterArray[i] != ' ' & (characterArray[i] < 'a' | characterArray[i] > 'z'))  throw new Exception("Invalid character. Expected lowercase basic latin letters and spaces only.");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `input.next()`, which reads the input *up to the next white space character*, use `input.nextLine()`. This will give you the complete line (without the end-of-line character, of course).